# Capturing Text from Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I'm trying to create a pivot table that has 2 parts.

In order to push parameters into the table, you would add allows users to filter across any one of several parameters in a field. For instance, you can filter by country, state/province, or county, each in a different box, and the pivot table would display the cities in each country, state/province, etc. 
The filter would also find the corresponding information in the data and fill in what state, country, or county.

It's sort of like a 2 part table. One is a form with fields you can filter by and the second would then filter the pivot table according to the filter preferences.

If I search for LA County, the filter fields would show Burbank, Pasadena, etc. and also fill in the filter fields for Country and state. Is this possible?

This is the concept I'm looking to do:

https://plus.google.com/photos/102081958215068478664/albums/6090870314834614881

Comment: Can you mock up what you would like to see and post a screen shot? It is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: The computer says that I need 10 reputations before I can post an image.

Comment: Be creative. Use a file sharing site. Post a link. If the computer says that you can't post a link, just post the url as text. Some people here will be able to copy and paste that into the address bar of their browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter a pivot table by values entered in cells, you need VBA. Here are some scenarios:

http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2014/05/15/change-pivot-table-filters-with-drop-down-cell/
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gabhan_berry/archive/2008/01/31/using-cell-text-to-filter-pivottables.aspx

Consider that with Excel 2010 you can also use slicers to filter a pivot table. If you use slicers instead of cells, you won't need any VBA and the slicers can be set up to dim items with no data, i.e. if you select Florida, the counties in other states will be dimmed.

[image]